# How to do multiple annotations for the same class with different properties

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I have following configuration. Please suggest how to annotate that class for the same purpose without xml file configuration.

```
    <bean id="validationBeanHelper" class="com.xxx.service.impl.ValidationBeanHelper">
    <property name="fileDAO" ref="fileDAO"/>
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="castorMarshaller"/>
    <property name="paymentMetricDAO" ref="paymentMetricDAO"/>
    <property name="workflowManager" ref="workflowManager"/>
    <property name="validationType" ref="DATA_VALIDATION"/>
    <property name="validators">
        <list>
            <ref bean="tifDataValidator" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="postProcessingValidationBeanHelper" class="com.xxx.service.impl.ValidationBeanHelper">
    <property name="fileDAO" ref="fileDAO"/>
    <property name="paymentMetricDAO" ref="paymentMetricDAO"/>
    <property name="workflowManager" ref="workflowManager"/>
    <property name="validationType" ref="POST_PROCESSING_VALIDATION"/>

    <property name="validators">
        <list>
            <ref bean="tifToleranceValidator" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: If you only have a single class, how do you expect the annotations to inject the 'correct' values for a given instance? A different strategy might be to have a base class and a pair of subclasses in which you annotate the setters for properties in the base.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Annotations like `@Service` and `@Inject` assume that there is only one bean defined for that class. And in your case you need two beans.

If you don't want xml, you can use [java-config](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java), but the premise remains: you have two beans, so you have to manually wire them.